# Use of suffix "phobe" or "phobia" for hatred?

Tags: etymology

The words that come to mind are "islamophobia" and "homophobia" but I am sure there are other examples. At the same time, there are many cases where the suffix means simply fear (although people will say, "I HATE heights").

To me, "hatred" is a very different word than "fear" although there is often overlap. Is the use of the suffix to mean "dislike" a more recent usage or is the meaning of "hate" such that it is far more than disdain and it implies fear in addition to disdain?